# Flip second div and third div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four div and my query is that i want to replace the order of second div and third div the output should come in this way 1324 instead of 1234

```
<div class="bar">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    reverseChildren($('.bar'));
    if (document.body.offsetWidth < 600) {  
        function reverseChildren($parent) {
            var listItems = $parent.children('div');
            console.log(listItems);
            $parent.append(listItems.get().reverse());
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you defining a function in an `if` statement? Your code is very odd.

Comment: Please next time improve your code formatting / indenting and add a jsfiddle for easy testing, like I did.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have define if condition because when the screen width is 600 then this code will run, but the problem is that it run but output come in 4321 and i need 1324..plz suggest me

Comment: @AshishSingh Then it's still rather wierd you are wrapping your function with an if statement, that will throw errors when the site is wider then 600. You should wrap the function *call* instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the position of two elements using [jQuery's before method](http://api.jquery.com/before/).

```
$('.bar div:nth-child(2)').before($('.bar div:nth-child(3)'));
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78uyq5p5/) of it using your html.

Also, function declarations should not be inside an **if statement** if you are trying to call the function outside of the **if statement**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you've wrapped your function call within an if statement, which is very odd. You should wrap the function call with the if statement and make the function call itself globally available.

Second: your function now selects all children and reverses them, while you only want to select the last item of the two you would like to reverse and append it before it's immedeate previous sibling like so:

**html**

```
<div class="bar">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function reverseChild($parent, index)
{
    // Retrieve the child item with the supplied (ZERO BASED!) index
    var childItem = $parent.children('div:eq(' + index + ')');

    // Place it in front of it's immedeate previous sibling.
    childItem.prev().before(childItem);
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    reverseChild($('.bar'), 2);
});
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mpcowmpb/

- Do note: i've removed the document.body.offsetWidth check within the JSFiddle demo as the body's less wide within that demo.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Jamin for help

Comment: The resulting DOM structure is not correct.  Also noticed that on my answer.  Have deleted it as @DanArl's is doing the trick.  Perhaps update yours to make the structure correct.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: hi @Dennis are you there i need one more help could u please go through this and help me tosort out the issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845185/flip-div-element?noredirect=1#comment40437968_25845185

Comment: First start accepting answers that helped you fix your issue. Also: it's not really accepted to bump questions like this.