# Flip div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="bar">
  <div id="h2"> 01 </div>
  <div id="h2"> 02 </div>
  <div id="h2"> 03 </div>
  <div class="h1"> 1
    <div id="a1"> 8 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="h2"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

```js
function reverseChild($parent, index) {
  var childItem = $parent.children('div:eq(' + index + ')');
  childItem.prev().before(childItem);
};


$(document).ready(function () {
  reverseChild($('#bar h1'), 1);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqrkjkkz/)

my query is that i need this output

```
01
02
03
1
2
8
```

but it showing

```
01
02
03
1
8
2
```

Comment: ID's are unique. you shouldnt use #h2 more than once. your selector isnt working.. $('#bar h1') doesnt exist since there is no h1. you want the class .h1 $('#bar').find('.h1') - and it would be great if you can explain what exactly you want to archive - is this some sort of ordering items or just exchanging 2 random items you pass to a function?

Comment: thank@Gulty but putting $('#bar .h1') still it not work kindly tell me the exact code to do this., actually i am sort the ordering item instead of 01 02 03 1 8 2 i want 01 02 03 1 2 8 hope u can understand what i am trying to do it.

Comment: my brain is aching with this one ... one of the reasons is the multiple id with the same value but the other reason is i don't see what you intend with this. What do you intend? Is it only to use jQuery to swap <div id="a1"> 8 </div> with <div id="h2"> 2 </div>?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/fa4txjuv/1/

just click on this u can understand what i am trying to get

Comment: Do you really want a function for that? You want to interchange these divs specifically or to do this to a bunch of similar cases?

Comment: <div class="h1">1
 <div id="a1">8</div>
    </div>
    <div id="h2">2</div>

and I want 

    <div class="h1">1
 <div id="h2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="a1">8</div>  with this dom structure

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result with the following jQuery ... see [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v75anwyh/)

HTML

```
<div id="bar">
  <div id="h2"> 01 </div>
  <div id="h2"> 02 </div>
  <div id="h2"> 03 </div>
  <div class="h1"> 1
    <div id="a1"> 8 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="h2"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var last= $('#bar > div:last-child').clone(),
    inner = $('#a1').clone();

$('#bar > div:last').remove();
$('#bar').append(inner);

$('.h1').children().remove();
$('.h1').append(last);
```

Comment: This outputs the intended result ... I'm just not sure you want this method to accomplish it.

Comment: thanks @henser but the thing which i want in this formant when u see your DOm structure i want the dom structure in this way 
    <div class="h1">1
  <div id="h2">2</div> 
    </div>
   <div id="a1">8</div>
and your code is showing this 
    <div class="h1">1</div>
 <div id="h2">2</div> 
    <div id="a1">8</div>

Comment: i want to replacee this  <div id="a1"> 8 </div> to  <div id="h2"> 2 </div> in short interchange the whole div

Comment: @AshishSingh I've edited my answer ... the following jQuery snippet will achieve what you described as being the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small swap script for ordering items - it's currently not working for '01' since I convert this to an integer to compare them. Anyway you can implement some extra checks for this if you like to.

HTML:

```
<div id="bar">
  <div class="h2">1</div>
  <div class="h2">8</div> 
  <div class="h2">2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#bar').find('.h2').each(function(){
    var currentItem = $(this),
        nextItem = $(this).next('.h2'),
        currentItemValue = parseInt(currentItem.text()),
        nextItemValue = parseInt(nextItem.text());

    if(currentItemValue > nextItemValue) {
        currentItem.before(nextItem);
    }

  });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqrkjkkz/3/)

This is a more dynamic approach to swap elements depending on it's innerHtml. Maybe it's what you want

Comment: <div class="h1">1
 <div id="a1">8</div>
    </div>
    <div id="h2">2</div>

and I want 

    <div class="h1">1
 <div id="h2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="a1">8</div>  with this dom structure

Comment: this is a dynamic sort structure. means every element you wanna sort has the same class.. otherwise this only works for 2 elements which isn't a good practise since you have to adopt it for multiple elements you wanna sort. just give each element you wanna use the function a class like '.sort' and replace the '.h2' in the js with the class you added for the sortable elements.

Answer (score -1):

**JQuery**

```
function reverseChild($parent, index,$replaceObj) {
    var childItem = $parent.children().eq(index-1);
    var replaceObjIndex=$replaceObj.index()+1;
    $replaceObj.insertAfter(childItem);
    insertAtIndex("bar",replaceObjIndex,childItem);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    reverseChild($('#bar .h1'), 1,$("#bar").children('div:last'));
});
function insertAtIndex(objID,i,$insertItem) {
    if(i === 0) {
     $("#"+objID).prepend($insertItem);        
     return;
    }
    $("#"+objID+" > div:nth-child(" + (i-1) + ")").after($insertItem);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/4wb30jg1/1/)

Comment: This fiddle doesn't provide the desired output

Comment: thanks @hamix but the output which i want is this
01
02
03
1
2
8

Comment: thanks @laapostos but i need this structure
    <div class="h1">1
 <div id="a1">8</div>
    </div>
    <div id="h2">2</div>

and I want 

    <div class="h1">1
 <div id="h2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="a1">8</div>  with this dom structure